# I am unable to Add a file from my windows machine to alpine image in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am taking a docker tutorial course and one of the lesson creates a docker file where we:

1. Create a container from an alpine image
2. Install java into that image
3. Set the environment path so javac can be executed in the image
4. Change the working directory to a specified directory
5. Add Test.java file from my windows machine to the working directory in the image mentioned in step 4
6. Compile the Test.java file and then run it.

I have created the following dockerfile in my windows machine:

Here is my dockerfile content:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add openjdk8
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin
WORKDIR /usr/share/udemy
ADD Test.java Test.java
ENTRYPOINT javac Test.java && java Test
```

This is the error message I am getting from the container:

```
javac: file not found: /usr/share/udemy/Test.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I should be getting a "Hello-world!!!" on my cmd prompt

what am I doing wrong. I followed the tutorial to the dot and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you change ENTRYPOINT to CMD, you can `docker run --rm -it imagename sh` to get an interactive shell on the built image and poke around.  (There’s also a `--entrypoint` option, but it using a awkward little is.)

Comment: Your dockerfile doesn't look bad, but I am curious about one thing that could be causing your issue.
Where are you running the docker command from? Could you run the command `dir` and show the output for us? Also, could you show us the command you're using to build and run the docker image?

Comment: @Joshua when I execute the dir command I get a list of the files in the folder:

`Docker Notes.txt`
`docker-commands.pdf`
`DockerFile`
`Test.java`

I use the following command to build: `docker build -t=oribta1frame/hello-word .`

and to run:
`docker run orbita1frame/hello-world`

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran the following command:

`docker run --rm -it orbita1frame/hello-world sh` and I don't get an interactive shell. I get the same error message as before and it exists.

Comment: Did you notice you have a spelling mistake in your comment? `oribta1frame` vs. `orbita1frame` and `hello-word` vs. `hello-world` didn't know if you copy/pasted or just typed it out. However, I ran your commands and fixed the typo with a simple hello world and it worked for me. I'm struggling to see your issue, but I'll continue looking.

Comment: I would use `COPY` instead of `ADD` since you aren't using `ADD`'s special extraction features. Also, the second argument for `ADD`/`COPY` should be destination, so it should be a directory/path not just a file name (maybe that does work like it is tho). Finally, is `Test.java` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`? It should be.

Comment: @Joshua yeah those were just simple mistakes I made when typing the reply.
@Perplexabot I set the WORKDIR to the location that I want my container to start from and then copy the file in the next line which should put it under `/usr/share/udemy` in the contiainer.

Comment: OK, it works but don't know why now lol. I took out the last ENTRYPOINT line and built an image to verify that the file and working directories were indeed being set correctly and they were. I then added the line back in and rebuilt the image from scratch and ran the container. It started working as expected. I'm still perplexed though. Thanks for all your help guys!!!!